# Not able to make new oracle db connection in sqldeveloper

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sid

While I am able to connect through SQL PLUS using 'system' user. A bit while connecting in SQL Developer it is throwing the error:
Status: Failure - Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error: `ORA-12505, TNS: listener does not currently know of SID given in...`

Comment: sqlplus can connect w/o a properly running/configured listener. on the db server, run lsnrctl - status and make sure your db is listed along with the services being supported, then make sure your sqldev connection is trying to connect to one of those

Answer (score 0):

Value you're inserting into SQL Developer's **SID** field enter into its **Service Name** field.